# redux-form Field with custom component - default value?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I'm trying to set default values for some `Field`s in my form that use a custom component but I can't quite get it to work. The reason I want to do that is because when I press the submit button I get `undefined` as values for the `Field`s that do not have a value. For that reason I would like to specify a default value for the `Field` to be initialized with, but I can't figure out how to do that when passing a custom component to the field.

This is my form

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import CustomInput from './CustomInput';

class ProfileForm extends Component {
    render() {
        const {
            handleSubmit,
            error,
            submitting
        } = this.props;

        return (
            <form className='registerform' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className='form-panel'>
                    <label>
                        Persoonlijke gegevens
                    </label>
                    <div className='row row-small'>
                        <div className='col-xs-5'>
                            <Field name='firstName'
                                className='form-group'
                                inputClassName='form-control'
                                component={CustomInput}
                                type='text'
                                placeholder='Voornaam'
                                defaultValue='some lastName' />
                        </div>
                        <div className='col-xs-7'>
                            <Field name='lastName'
                                className='form-group'
                                inputClassName='form-control'
                                component={CustomInput}
                                type='text'
                                placeholder='Achternaam'
                                defaultValue='some firstName' />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className='form-panel'>
                    <button type='submit' className='btn btn-big btn-blue btn-full uppercase' disabled={submitting}>
                        {
                            submitting &&
                            <span>Opslaan...</span>
                        }
                        {
                            !submitting &&
                            <span>Opslaan</span>
                        }
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

ProfileForm = reduxForm({
    form: 'profile'
})(ProfileForm);

export default connect()(ProfileForm);
```

In the above code sample I tried to use `defaultValue` attribute to set the default value, as per the documentation [here](https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/docs/api/field.md/), however this didn't work and I also noticed this version of the documentation was outdated, the most recent version does not seem to have a `defaultValue` attribute.

This is my `CustomInput` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';

class CustomInput extends Component {
    render() {
        let {
            input,
            placeholder,
            type,
            className,
            inputClassName,
            showLabel,
            meta: { touched, error }
        } = this.props;

        if (error) {
            inputClassName += ' invalid';
        }

        let inputElement = <input {...input} className={inputClassName} type={type} placeholder={placeholder} />;
        if (type === 'textarea') {
            inputElement = <textarea {...input} className={inputClassName} placeholder={placeholder} />;
        }

        return (
            <div className={className}>
                {
                    showLabel &&
                    <label>{placeholder}</label>
                }
                {inputElement}                
                {
                    error &&
                    <span>
                        {error}
                    </span>
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

CustomInput.defaultProps = {
    showLabel: false
};

export default CustomInput;
```

How do I pass along a default value to my `CustomInput` component? The default value could be different for each instance of `CustomInput`, so I don't want to store the default value in there. Any help would be greatly appreciated.